# Não é possível salvar no calendário nativo - Xamarin - IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, calendar

Estou salvando um evento no calendário nativo do IOS através do código abaixo, pelo simulador funciona perfeitamente, mas quando faço direto no aparelho do Iphone este código não funciona.
Fiz dois testes o primeiro abrindo o calendário para o usuário visualizar e depois salvar e nesse caso exibe a mensagem que não e possível salvar o evento, no segundo mandei salvar direto sem precisar que o usuário clicasse no salvar do calendário, nesse caso ele salvo gerou o Id do evento mas não aparece no calendário, mas se busca pelo ios ele encontra o evento clicamos no evento abre o calendário e não aparece o evento.
Alguém já teve esse problema ou tem ideia do que pode ser ?
Já usei o exemplo do Xamarin sem alterar nada e deu o mesmo problema.

******* PRIMEIRO TESTE *******

```
EventKitUI.EKEventEditViewController eventController = new EventKitUI.EKEventEditViewController();
DateTime reference = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
eventController.Event = EKEvent.FromStore(App.Current.EventStore);
eventController.Event.StartDate = (NSDate)DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
eventController.Event.EndDate = (NSDate)DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(40);
eventController.Event.Title = "TITLE";
eventController.Event.Notes = "NOTE";
eventControllerDelegate = new CreateEventEditViewDelegate(eventController);
eventController.EditViewDelegate = eventControllerDelegate;
PresentViewController(eventController, true, null);
```

******* SEGUNDO TESTE *******

```
EKEvent newEvent = EKEvent.FromStore(App.Current.EventStore);
newEvent.AddAlarm(EKAlarm.FromDate((NSDate)DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)));
newEvent.StartDate = (NSDate)DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
newEvent.EndDate = (NSDate)DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(40);
newEvent.Title = "TITLE";
newEvent.Notes = "NOTE";
newEvent.Calendar = App.Current.EventStore.DefaultCalendarForNewEvents;
NSError e;
App.Current.EventStore.SaveEvent(newEvent, EKSpan.ThisEvent, out e);
if (e != null)
{
new UIAlertView("Err Saving Event", e.ToString(), null, "ok", null).Show();
return;
}
else
{
new UIAlertView("Event Saved", "Event ID: " + newEvent.EventIdentifier, null, "ok", null).Show();
}
```

Comment: Você poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Você está no StackOverflow em Português.

Comment: Estou salvando um evento normalmente no calendário nativo do IOS através do código acima pelo simulador, mas quando faço direto no aparelho do Iphone este código não funciona exibindo a mensagem que não e possível salvar o evento